# Active Directory User - SUDO

Tags: sudo, active-directory

Let me preface this by saying that I am a bit of a Linux newbie.  So, situation is, I have joined a Ubuntu server to a local Active Directory domain.  This appears to have been successful since I can use an active directory user to login to the machine.

I have also edited the `sudoers` file with the `$linux_admin_group` (all) all priveleges.

When I run sudo -l for this particular user, i get

```
User xxxxx may run the following commands on ip-172xxxx: (All) ALL
```

But, when I try to run any `sudo restart tomcat` or `sudo nano xxx` I get prompted for a password and receive the message

```
Sorry, user xxxx is not allowed to execute '/xxx ' as root on IP172....
```

What step am I missing as to be able to use these specified active directory group users as having 'admin' rights on this Ubuntu server?

Comment: Did you try using su?

Comment: Don't I have to specify a user when trying su alone?  What user name would I specify?  currently the 'admin' user is just Ubuntu with no password.  We use a SSH key to authenticate.

Comment: Perhaps try `sudo -i` to see if you can become the root user. Then you do not need to use the sudo command to restart tomcat or edit a file.

Comment: It always asks for a root password but root is disabled I believe by default so will 'root' have to be enabled

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was specific to where you enter the % (ALL).

For sudo it needed to be directly under the existing sudo entry

i.e.

## allow members of the group sudo ....

%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%    ALL=(ALL) ALL